# Confusion about some code in an Android Room with a View sample project

Tags: android, android-room

I am learning the android room with a view. I've looked through some sample projects and tutorials and there is one thing in this example that I am hung up on and that I do not understand. Here is the code (underneath the code I point out the few lines I'm confused about):

```
public class NewWordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



public static final String EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY";

   private  EditText mEditWordView;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_word);
       mEditWordView = findViewById(R.id.edit_word);

       final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_save);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
               if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditWordView.getText())) {
                   setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent);
               } else {
                   String word = mEditWordView.getText().toString();
                   replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, word);
                   setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
               }
               finish();
           }
       });
   }
}
```

The parts that I am confused about are the second line, the EXTRA_REPLY, and then you can see it used toward the bottom in reply.Intent.putExtra. What is the EXTRA_REPLY pointing to exactly? How would you find it in your own project?

Here is the source of the sample if you need more context: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make an intent you can add extra data to it in key-value form. In this example they use the string constant `EXTRA_REPLY` as the key, and the variable `word` as the value.

The recipient of the intent would access the data by using `intent.getStringExtra(NewWordActivity.EXTRA_REPLY)`.

It's good practice to define the keys for your intents as constants so that you're less likely to make mistakes when referencing it in other classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a simple key/value pair. Like a `HashMap`, or a `Dictionary`.

```
replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, word);
```

This will set the `EXTRA_REPLY` to `word` within your `Intent` so you can read it in whatever `Activity` is handling your result.

You can also do it with a `Bundle`, for example when you launch a new `Activity`.

The key, `com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY`, does not really matter, just make sure that everyone is using the same key.